# Cast generic T to bool via object?

Tags: c#, generics

Why do I need to cast a generic type `T` to `object` first, before I can cast it to a `bool`?

Can I constraint `T` so that I can cast it to `bool` directly?

e.g.

```
    public void Set<T>(T value)
    {
        if (typeof (T) == typeof (bool))
        {
            Manager.SetValue(ID, (bool) (object) value);
        }
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Because `T` can be any `Type`, not only `bool`. That's the purpose of generic types.

Comment: That doesn't explain why I have to cast it to `object` before I am allowed to cast it to `bool`. I understand what generics are.

Comment: Very good question! Jon Skeet answers your first question in another SO question, so I'm marking this one as a duplicate. As to your second question: Nope, such a constraint is not possible as far as I know.

Comment: @Heinzi google-d for this for quite a bit, care to link the answer? Thx in advance

Comment: @bas: Just follow the link which is now at the top of your question, it's the first (and accepted) answer.

Comment: Right. Casting can be done only from compatible types or from object. As the type of T is not known, it cannot be casted directly to type 'X'. So `(X)value` will not work, while `(X)(object)value` will work.

Comment: @Heinzi, Jon Skeet always knows doesn't he :). But, that helps understanding, good to know that `as` operator will work as well. PS: sorry for the dumb comment, didn't refresh this page yet so didn't realise the link was there already

Comment: Notice that `as` works only for reference types, so it will not work for `bool`.

Comment: @ArghyaC ah right, good one.